# Автоматическая подстановка текста при перепосте в соц.сети

Tags: javascript, facebook, ya-share2, соцсети

использую код яндекс кнопок для репостов соц сети материалов сайта.
По умолчанию подхватывается изображение, тайтл и описание.
Подскажите, а возможно ли подставлять еще текст в поле сообщения (поле, где пользователь ручками пишет), к примеру, "я прочел статью и вам советую".

Спасибо.